# Override Class in PHPUnit Feature Test

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to test a custom Artisan command which does multiple things and then at the end does a csv import.  I instantiate the object manually `new CsvDirectDatabaseImporter` inside the artisan command. This runs a method called `import()` which imports from csv to database using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` which is not supported by SQLite. Since I want my tests to run in memory I want to override (or mock/stub not sure what the correct term is) the import method on the CsvDirectDatabaseImporter class so it doesn't do anything during the import call. This way the rest of my tests will work (I know now I'm not testing the actual import) How would I go around this:

Here is a simplified version my Artisan Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Services\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter;
use App\Services\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter\MyColumns;

class DataMartImport extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'myimport:import
                            {year : The year of processing} ';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'My Import';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $year = $this->argument('year');

        // Copy the file to processing location.
        File::copy($files[0], $processing_file);

        // Import the CSV File.
        $csvImporter = new CsvDirectDatabaseImporter($processing_file, 'myTable', new MyColumns());
        $csvImporter->import();
    }

}
```

A simplified version of a Feature test of running my custom artisan command:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Console\DataMart;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Mockery as m;
use App\Services\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter\DataMartColumns;
use App\Services\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class MyImportTest extends TestCase
{


    public function testImportFoldersGetCreatedIfNoDirectory()
    {
        $year = 2019;

        $this->artisan('myimport:import', ['year' => $year]);

        // Assertions of items go here unrelated to the actual database import.
    }

}
```

CSVImorter Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File as CSV_File;

class CsvDirectDatabaseImporter {

    /**
     * File to import.
     *
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * Table name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $table;

    /**
     * Fields terminated by.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $fieldsTerminatedBy = '\',\'';

    /**
     * Enclosed by.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $enclosedBy = '\'"\'';

    /**
     * Lines terminated by.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $linesTerminatedBy = '\'\n\'';

    /**
     * Ignore first row.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $ignoreFirstRow = true;

    /**
     * Csv Import columns.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $columns;

    /**
     * CsvImporter constructor.
     *
     * @param string $path
     *   The full temporary path to the file
     */
    public function __construct(string $path, $table, CsvDirectDatabaseImportColumns $columns)
    {
        $this->file = new CSV_File($path);
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->columns = $columns->getColumns();
    }

    /**
     * Import method used for saving file and importing it using database query.
     */
    public function import()
    {
        // Normalize line endings
        $normalized_file = $this->normalize($this->file);

        // Import contents of the file into database
        return $this->importFileContents($normalized_file, $this->table, $this->columns);
    }

    /**
     * Convert file line endings to uniform "\r\n" to solve for EOL issues
     * Files that are created on different platforms use different EOL characters
     * This method will convert all line endings to Unix uniform
     *
     * @param string $file_path
     * @return string $file_path
     */
    protected function normalize($file_path)
    {
        // Load the file into a string.
        $string = @file_get_contents($file_path);

        if (!$string) {
            return $file_path;
        }

        // Convert all line-endings using regular expression.
        $string = preg_replace('~\r\n?~', "\n", $string);

        file_put_contents($file_path, $string);

        return $file_path;
    }

    /**
     * Import CSV file into Database using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function
     *
     * NOTE: PDO settings must have attribute PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
     *
     * @param string $file_path
     *   File path.
     * @param string $table_name
     *   Table name.
     * @param array $columns
     *   Array of columns.
     *
     * @return mixed Will return number of lines imported by the query
     */
    private function importFileContents($file_path, $table_name, $columns)
    {
        $prefix = config('database.connections.mysql.prefix');
        $query = '
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'' . $file_path . '\' INTO TABLE `' . $prefix . $table_name . '`
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' . $this->fieldsTerminatedBy . '
            ENCLOSED BY ' . $this->enclosedBy . '
            LINES TERMINATED BY ' . $this->linesTerminatedBy . '
            ';
        if ($this->ignoreFirstRow) {
            $query .= ' IGNORE 1 ROWS ';
        }

        if ($columns) {
            $query .= '(' . implode(",\n", array_keys($columns)) . ')';

            $query .= "\nSET \n";

            $sets = [];
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $sets[] = $column['name'] . ' = ' . $column['set'];
            }
            $query .= implode(",\n", $sets);
        }

        return DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($query);
    }
}
```

CsvDirectDatabaseImportColumns Interface

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\CsvDirectDatabaseImporter;

interface CsvDirectDatabaseImportColumns
{

    /**
     * Returns array of columns.
     *
     * Ex:
     *   '@user_id' => [
     *     'name' =>  'user_id',
     *     'set' => '@user_id',
     *   ],
     *   '@agent_number' => [
     *     'name' =>  'agent_number',
     *     'set' => 'LEFT(@agent_number, 7)',
     *   ],
     *
     * The key should be the column name of the csv but add @ in front. The name
     * will be the database table.  The set will be what it s se
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function columns();

    /**
     * Returns columns.
     *
     * @return array
     *   Columns.
     */
    public function getColumns();
}
```

**Things I tried**

```
$mock = $this->createMock(CsvDirectDatabaseImporter::class);
        $mock->method('import')->willReturn(true);
        $this->app->instance(CsvDirectDatabaseImporter::class, $mock);
$this->artisan('datamart:import', ['year' => $year]);
```

But no luck there. It still runs the regular import() method.

Comment: Can we have the `CsvDirectDatabaseImporter` class code so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have added the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have tried to reproduce what I think you need into a simple example

Let's say we have this command

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Foo extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'foo';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->import()) {
            $this->info('Success');
        } else {
            $this->error('Failed');
        }
    }

    public function import()
    {
        throw new Exception('An exception that should not be thrown');
    }
}
```

The import method throws an exception but here's how to mock it to return true

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Console\Commands\Foo;

class FooCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)->setMethods(['import'])->getMock();
        $mock->method('import')->willReturn(true);
        $this->app->instance('App\Console\Commands\Foo', $mock);
        $this->artisan('foo')
            ->expectsOutput('Success')
            ->assertExitCode(0);
    }
}
```

This test passes with two successful assertion, so you can adjust your command code to use a dedicated method for the import

Hope this helps